# how do you display a image from a if statement

Tags: javascript, html, image

```html
<img id="myImg">
<script>
    var deck = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52];

    function myFunction() {
        deck.sort(function(a, b) {
            return 0.5 - Math.random()
        });
        deck.shift();
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = deck;
        document.getElementById("player1").innerHTML = deck[0];

        if (deck[0] == '1') {
            document.getElementById("myImg").style.display = 'inline';
        } else if (deck[0] == '2') {
            alert("I am an alert box!");
```

This is the code I got. I need it to make a image display in a specific location.

Comment: Where is the rest of the source code..... like the rest of the `deck` array where it's defined.... and where `d` is defined...

Comment: @NewToJS added it

Comment: Open your browser console. Check for error reports, that would be the first place to look and use `console.log()` for debugging/testing values.

Comment: @NewToJS no errors i think i am just using the wrong code

Comment: it's not really clear what your question is.  you have a random `img` tag that you are changing the style of inside the `if` statement.  It's not obvious how this would affect screen position, since we can't see any of the surrounding HTML.  It's also not clear what might happen if the condition is anything other than `1` or `2`, or how you are testing any of this.

Comment: Do you have CSS that is hiding the image? How are you planning on populating the `src` attribute of the image?

Comment: @claies I need code to display a image if he if statement is correct

Comment: "I need code" isn't really a question, and it's certainly not the kind of thing that gets answers here....

Comment: Well to display/change the image you can use `document.getElementById("myImg").src="Path-To-New-Image.jpg"/>` the `src` attribute is the source for the image tag so by setting/changing the `src` attribute you will be displaying a new image. That's the best I can give you without seeing the rest of the relevant source code and your question does lack detail.

Comment: I would recommend that you take a read through [ask];  you might be able to improve both questions you tried to ask tonight.

Comment: this is all of the code http://jsfiddle.net/f5kr87tu/ i cant get my head around displaying the img

Comment: there is no image in the code in that fiddle to display.

Comment: @DeadPixle I'm still finding it hard to understand what it is you want but I have worked an example into your existing jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/f5kr87tu/1/ is this game supposed to have 4 players and each player gets 4 cards from the deal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few errors:

Missing `}`

See snippet

note: I added an image and set its display property to none.

If the snippet is run several times and you are lucky enough to obtain an array with first and second elements as `1` and `2` respectively, You'll notice the if statements are executed

```css
img {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<img id="myImg" src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTkb6sdx_0T-5Pb34CB1_x1ILIQIErjC5C1kA8cIrxDclawMiMK">
<div id="demo"></div>
<div id="player1"></div>
<script>
  var deck = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52];

  function myFunction() {
    deck.sort(function(a, b) {
      return 0.5 - Math.random()
    });
    deck.shift();
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = deck;
    document.getElementById("player1").innerHTML = deck[0];
    if (deck[0] == 1) {
      document.getElementById("myImg").style.display = 'inline';
    } else if (deck[0] == 2) {
      alert("I am an alert box!");
    }
  }
  myFunction()
</script>
```